# Filling a table by iterating over a sequence produces an orphan cell

Tags: tables, expl3, xparse

I'm trying to fill a table with content that is stored in a sequence by a custom command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \my_sequence

\NewDocumentCommand{\addToMySequence}{mmm}{ \seq_gput_right:Nn \my_sequence {#1 & #2 & #3 \\ \hline} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillTable}{}{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \my_sequence
    {
        ##1
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addToMySequence{a}{b}{c}
\addToMySequence{d}{e}{f}
\addToMySequence{g}{h}{i}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \fillTable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The code basically works as expected, but produces an orphan cell at the end of the table:

[image: orphan cell]

This also happens if you comment out all calls to `\addToMySequence` or the `##1` inside the iteration. So it must come from somewhere inside that command.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the loop started by `\seq_map_inline:Nn` realizes the sequence has ended only after the last `\hline` has been issued and so a new cell is started. You can exploit `\seq_use`, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq
\tl_new:N \l_hurzelchen_table_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\addToMySequence}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq  {#1 & #2 & #3 \\ \hline}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillTable}{}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_hurzelchen_table_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_hurzelchen_table_tl { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_hurzelchen_table_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addToMySequence{a}{b}{c}
\addToMySequence{d}{e}{f}
\addToMySequence{g}{h}{i}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \fillTable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that every variable name should be prefixed by `g` (global usage), `l` (local usage) or `c` (global constant) and end with the variable type.

[image]

An alternative way, which can come handy if we have to do more things with the sequence and not only deliver it, is to build the whole table in a token list and deliver this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addToMySequence}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq  {#1 & #2 & #3 \\ \hline}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillTable}{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq { }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addToMySequence{a}{b}{c}
\addToMySequence{d}{e}{f}
\addToMySequence{g}{h}{i}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \fillTable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This completely performs the loop in the first cell, so the problem with the orphan cell disappears.

Comment: with your fix, I get this error:
`! Undefined control sequence.
\fillTable ->\seq_use:Nn 
                         \g_hurzelchen_cells_seq {}
l.29     \fillTable`

Comment: and actually... shouldn't the last `\\ \hline` result in the end of the "g h i"-row with the bottom border?

Comment: @Hurzelchen `\seq_use:Nn` has been added in the 2013-05-26 release, so you have an outdated expl3 suite. I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @Hurzelchen Oh, sorry! I changed the sequence name in only one place

Comment: Your second solution works perfect for me, thanks!

I think you just mixed up the two code blocks and their descriptions ;)